# error TS2740 on Angular when trying to load .json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am a novice in Angular/Typescript and I am trying to build a dynamic page with the champion_info.json in order to display all the data in a list. I tried to upload the data from my json file but I have this error and I don't know what to do about it. I watched every possible youtube video about this subject but I still can't find an answer.

How can I simply load my data from the .json file and use it in order to display it in a list ?

This is my hero.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Heroes from "src/hero_json/champion_info.json";

interface heroes1 {
  title: String;
  id: Number;
  name: String;
  key:String;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})
export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  liste !: heroes1 = Heroes;

  constructor() {
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
    
}
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4T2d.png)

And this is where you can find the champion_info.json file: https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/league-of-legends?select=champion_info.json

Comment: Assuming this: `liste !: heroes1` is a typo, and the code is actually as it was shown in the error: `list: heroes1[]`, you need to: 1) use the `data` property of `Heroes` 2) convert that to an array. Unfortunately that JSON is structured quite badly. The `data` is an object with keys: `"1", "2", etc..` while it should have been an array.

Comment: @tromgy This is EXACTLY my issue: that JSON with the keys won't let me have direct access to the data. Unfortunately my professor requires it. So I tried this:       
     `var json_data = Heroes;
    console.log(Object.values(json_data.data));`                                                                      Now I have this as my data: [ 0: {title: 'the Dark Child', id: 1, key: 'Annie', name: 'Annie'},1: {title: 'the Berserker', id: 2, key: 'Olaf', name: 'Olaf'} ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is you need to add

```
declare module "*.json" {
   const value: any;
   export default value;
}
```

in a file in the app folder as

```
json-typings.d.ts
```

Anyways here is the repo I create to answer your question with basic and complete way to build this app you can clone a try to u

[repor basic app](https://github.com/hamada-j/hero/tree/master/src)

Comment: hi @Hamada, thank you very miuch for this I can now display my data. Right now, I am trying to display all the data in an AG-grid but using the following code doesn't show anything in the grid:  `<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="arrHeroes"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"></ag-grid-angular>`       Do you have any idea of how I can display the same data in an this grid ?  This is my grid : `columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'id' },
    { field: 'nom' },
    { field: 'titre'}
  ];`

Comment: Great. In the same [repo](https://github.com/hamada-j/hero/tree/dev-ag-grid) in the "dev-ag-grid" branch, I add for u this library. Because this wait for an observable, will never work `[rowData]="arrHeroes"`, you need to flow the steps of the documentation install and config the library, and then I find a way to pass the array to observable with **RxJS**.

Comment: This is what data should be `rowData: Observable<any[]> | undefined;` I create this method to pass our array to observable `getHeroes(arrHeroes: any) { return of(arrHeroes); };` in the `ngOnInit() this.rowData = this.getHeroes(this.arrHeroes)`. Very important in the _HTML_ `[rowData]="rowData | async"` most be like, documentation tell. And done.

Comment: To fix the _width_ and _height_ for your needs, then add to **heroes.component.scss** the tag elemente with the key _!important_ `ag-grid-angular {
  width: 100% !important;
}`...happy coding

Comment: Thank you very much @Hamada you are really helping me finish this !! I still have a little issue : I tried to use Material Design to add a hero but I have a problem accessing the same data that you first displayed (all the heroes side by side). I tried this: `  getAllHeroes(){
    this.heroes.getJSON().subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{
        this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(res);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      },
      error:()=>{
        console.log("Erreur...");
      }
      
    })
  } `

Comment: I need your user in GitHub to add you as a collaborator to see your changes?

Comment: I create a [chat-room in StackOverFlow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242240/helping-ritz11) that we can chat there and not in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

First, as you have indicated above you need to get `.data` from the JSON object, in your component class:

```
heroes = json_data.data;
```

In your template use the angular [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe to parse and display data  where you have a list of objects rather than an array.

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | keyvalue">
  {{ hero.value.title }}
  {{ hero.value.name }}
  // etc
</div>
```